# Asynchronous snmp get calls in PHP

Tags: php, asynchronous, reactphp

is there a good way to make some PHP calls asynchronous, non-blocking?
For example, take a look at this simple code:

```
<?php
$hosts = [...]  // array of 100+ hosts
foreach ($hosts as $host){
  $sysNames['$host'] = snmpget($host, 'community', "system.sysName.0");
}
echo 'done'
```

If, for example, 10 hosts are down, that will make a huge delay.
**How to make snmpget calls non-blocking?** 


I've tried with React\Promise but I couldn't found some useful examples to start from. Can anyone suggest proper implementation of that class?

Comment: I think with async calls you wont be able to store the value in `$sysNames['$host']` by it's very nature you wont be waiting for the response, therefore there's likely no return data.  Or none that would be useful

Comment: I'm not aware of that class, but I use queues for all my long running processes to make them non blocking

Comment: @michael https://github.com/reactphp/promise

Comment: Is it ok to call snmpget in separate thread in this scenario? Since threads share memory with parent process, it would be possible that thread return value to $sysNames variable, no? If that's true how to tell last echo to wait all threads to finish?

Answer (score 0):

PHP supports multi-threading using the [threads](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pthreads.php) extensions; but it needs a properly build php-binary, plus some [additional dll's if you're on Windows](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads/)